# Prolog set a variable to fill constraints

Tags: prolog, logic

Is it possible to have the numbers 1-9 be placed such that it fills a constrain set out.

I have:

```
foo(bl1,A,B,C,Total1) :- A+B+C =:= Total1.
foo(bl2,A,B,D,Total2) :- A+B+D =:= Total2.

run_foo(A,B,C,D) :- 
    foo(bl1,A,B,C,13), 
    foo(bl2,A,B,D,11), 
    A/=B,
    A/=C,
    A/=D,
    B=/C,
    B=/D,
    C=/D.
```

And then run with something like:

```
run_foo(A,6,C,D).
```

So that it returns the values of `A`, `C` and `D`. This should return `A=4` ,`C=3`, `D=2`.

Comment: Since `A+B+C =:= Total` and `A+B+D =:= Total` then by basic algebra `D = C`., but you have `C=/D`, so what are your trying to do? Did I miss something?

Comment: Of interest: [Predicate =:=/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3A%3D)/2)

Comment: @GuyCoder The totals should be different, should that be reflected in the rule i.e. `foo(bl1,A,B,C,Total1)...` and `foo(bl2,A,B,D,Total2)`?

Comment: After your edit you now have to variables `<Set total1>` and `<Set total2>` that are never used. This makes the predicate `foo/5` meaningless as far as I can see.

Comment: The set totals are hard coded, but i can see where the confusion was.

Comment: This is of course something that clpfd would do much better, but without it, usually in these situations you wind up needing something to cause Prolog to generate values within your domain, such as `between(1, 9, A), between(1, 9, B), ...` etc.

Comment: Also it can be beneficial to use `dif/2` instead of `/=`, although this (bizarrely) is not ISO.

Comment: @EllisThompson Your both `foo/5` clauses perform identical tasks and have only their first parameter, unused in the body, as a difference which makes it meaningless. `foo/4` without that first atom parameter will do just fine. You differentiate `Total1` and `Total2` at the time of calling by supplying `13` and `11` respectively.

Comment: @DanielLyons: Why bizarrely? General `dif/2` requires constraints. In ISO, there are no constraints, but it is permitted as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constraints solver:

```
?- B #= 6, Vs = [A,B,C,D],
   Vs ins 1..9, A+B+C #= 13, A+B+D #= 11, all_distinct(Vs), label(Vs).
   B = 6, Vs = [2,6,5,3], A = 2, C = 5, D = 3
;  B = 6, Vs = [3,6,4,2], A = 3, C = 4, D = 2
;  B = 6, Vs = [4,6,3,1], A = 4, C = 3, D = 1.
```

Or:

```
?- B = 6, Vs = [A,B,C,D],
   maplist(between(1,9), Vs), A+B+C =:= 13, A+B+D =:= 11, \+ (select(V, Vs, Vs0), member(V, Vs0)).
   B = 6, Vs = [2,6,5,3], A = 2, C = 5, D = 3
;  B = 6, Vs = [3,6,4,2], A = 3, C = 4, D = 2
;  B = 6, Vs = [4,6,3,1], A = 4, C = 3, D = 1
;  false.
```